# MobilePush API call not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobilepush

I created a mobile push app in app center.

However, in the app center, it gives you AppID and Access Token. I grabbed the access token from app center and made the following call:

**Header :**

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: bearer 'Access token from app center'
```

**Body :**

```
{
"contactKey": "WRTest",
"attributeSets": [


{ 
"name": "MobilePush Demographics", 
"items": [{
"values": [{
"name": "Device ID",
"value": 958405948
},
{
"name": "Application",
"value": 958405948
}]
}]
}]
}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> {"message":"clientId is
>   required","errorcode":10002,"documentation":""}

Comment: What endpoint are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you called
 `https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken` 
with a body of

`{
  "clientId": "your client id",
  "clientSecret": "your client secret"
}`

to get a token for your fuel calls?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was following the wrong path. To create the access token I was using the credentials for Mobile Push App created in the app center.

To solve the issue, I created a new API app, generate the access token with the client id and client secret, and then used this token with mobile push app id.

Thanks

Comment: HI @chandan, is there a way around this?